Do AlternateBinding of XamDataGrid by Infragistics with DataItem
I have a code like this.
<igDP:Field
    Column="5"
    Row="2"
    Label="01"
    Name="A1"
    AllowEdit="True"
    Width="100"
    Height="24"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
    LabelTextAlignment="Center"
    BindingType="UseAlternateBinding">
    <igDP:Field.AlternateBinding>
        <Binding Path="" />
    </igDP:Field.AlternateBinding>
    <igDP:Field.Settings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings
            LabelMaxHeight="0"
            CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource dayDateStyle}">
        </igDP:FieldSettings>
    </igDP:Field.Settings>
    <igDP:Field.EditorStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type atoms:XamNumericEditor}" BasedOn="{StaticResource NumericEditorStyle1ALLNIGHT}"/>
    </igDP:Field.EditorStyle>
</igDP:Field>

What I really want to binding is DataItem.DailyWorkHours[1].AllNightWorkHours
ut it seems not possible as AlternateBinding can only binding my ViewModel. What should I do to binding it correctly?
And is it possible to make the key of Dictionary DailyWorkHours depends on the Name or Label of the Field? Such as Label is 01 so the key will be 1.
Also I'm using MVVM so I want to avoid code behind, thank you.
I tried to use ChatGPT but it only provide wrong information. May be it is providing the information of the old version Infragistics? I also tried to make NumericEditorStyle1ALLNIGHT to show the value of DataItem.DailyWorkHours[1] but it seems impossible to make the key of Dictionary DailyWorkHours depends on other properties.
